# Prevent redirection to root of site's origin after clicking push notification

Tags: service-worker, web-push

When using service workers for push notification on chrome, we show a push notification to the user. Clicking the notification generally opens the browser to the root of the site's origin.

Inside the callback of the following event:

`self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {})`

tried changing the window location url from '/' to '/redirectpage':

```
event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
type: "window"}).then(function(clientList) {
for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
  var client = clientList[i];
  if (client.url == '/' && 'focus' in client){
      return client.focus();
  }
}
if (clients.openWindow){
    //return clients.openWindow('/');
    return clients.openWindow('/redirectpage');//changed above code to this
}
}));
```

So the expected result, let's say on localhost should be http://localhost:8080/redirectpage. But clicking the notification still redirects me to the root of the site's origin which is http://localhost:8080.

Assuming this is the wrong way to do it, where do I need to specify the target url so that the browser opens this target url on click of push notification ?

Comment: Are you sure the `return client.focus();` code isn't being called? Can you remove that whole `for() {...}` loop while testing to confirm?

Comment: if http://localhost:8080/redirectpage is already opened then it won't open a new one. I am agree with Jeff Posnick, remove the entire for loop for testing purpose. it should work